# Div tag on al 4 corners CSS

Tags: css

im trying to place one Div with text and borders on each corner of the page and a link on the top center, i can place two divs at the right side with Float:Right, but i can't put the top left one in place, it slides down.
[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys5xr.png)
[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FprI7.png)

Comment: Please paste your code into the question here

Comment: Please put actual code, not images of it, into your question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. Also we need to see your HTML as its structure will be important.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example, positioning each element within the page using the top, bottom, left, right CSS properties.

The elements have been given a max width and a max height simply to ensure that they don't overlap but of course you will need to think about what layout you need on different viewport sizes depending on what content you have.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.page>*:nth-child(n) {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 33%;
  max-height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.page>.center {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.page>.top {
  top: 0;
}

.page>.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

.page>.left {
  left: 0;
}

.page>.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="top center">Top center</div>
  <div class="top left">Top left</div>
  <div class="top right">Top right</div>
  <div class="bottom left">Bottom left</div>
  <div class="bottom right">Bottom right</div>
</div>
```